# Showing half plane is open.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|Ax+By<C\}$, if I want to show the half plane is open can I just choose $\epsilon=\frac{|Aa+Bb-C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$, then would $B_{\epsilon}((a,b)) \subset A$, for an arbitrary $(a,b)$ in $A$?

Comment: I would choose $\epsilon/2$ because with radius $\epsilon$, it seems that the ball intersects the line.

Comment: Why make it complicated?  Without loss of generality, just take the upper-half plane.

Answer (score 2):

The upper half plane $U$ is open.  Therefore, with a rotation and translation, your half plane is open.

Let $z=(x,y)$ with $y>0.$  Then $B_{y/2}(z) \subset U.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you dont need to be that explicit. Since the distance is greater than 0, such epsilon exists. I say this because it will prove helpful in future exercises, where there is not (or you just don't know) a distance formula suiting your problem.